# SQL - Select rows from same table twice without using UNION

Tags: mysql

I have tables:

```
meal_categories
---------------------------
category_id | category_name
1           | Hot Drinks
2           | Cold Drinks
3           | Alcohol Drinks


meals
---------------------------------
meal_id | category_id | meal_name
1       | 1           | Tea
2       | 2           | Sprite
3       | 3           | Vodka + Sprite


meals_to_meals
------------------------
meal_id | mapped_meal_id
3       | 2
```

As you see, any meal can have any number of other meals (from same/other categories) inside it.

Let's say I need to display a category of **3rd** meal (**Vodka + Sprite**) and any sub-categories (and number of used meals inside them) if meal has it. So the result should be:

```
category_name  | total_meals
Alcohol Drinks | 1
Cold Drinks    | 1
```

If someone is confused what these numbers mean: **3rd** meal is in category Alcohol Drinks itself, so we have 1 And **3rd** meal also has 1 meal from category Cold Drinks inside, so I hope calculations make sense.

The biggest challenge for me was to select sub-meals of meals as separate rows. If I used JOIN query, it would return just a single row (even if it returns mapped meal id properly):

```
SELECT * FROM meals 
JOIN meals_to_meals
ON meals.meal_id=meals_to_meals.meal_id AND meals.meal_id=3
```

So after lots of search I decided to use UNION:

```
SELECT aaa.* FROM meals as aaa
JOIN meals_to_meals
ON aaa.meal_id=meals_to_meals.meal_id
GROUP BY aaa.meal_id
UNION ALL
SELECT meals.* FROM meals_to_meals
JOIN meals
ON meals_to_meals.mapped_meal_id=meals.meal_id
```

This one returns meals + mapped meals properly (as separate rows), but if I add further queries to display categories and number of meals inside them, I get error **The used SELECT statements have a different number of column**

I'm sure I could somehow manage to display categories, if I'm able to achieve the same result without using UNION (so the query would be easier for me to understand). Any ideas?

By the way, here's the fiddle, feel free to play with it - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64313b/8

Comment: Quantity does not equal quality, and I don't follow how you arrive at your expected output.

Comment: UNION IS pretty easy to understand it concatenates the results off both SELECTS together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNION ALL` is already the best approach, as long as this is just two levels (a drink can consist of other drinks, but a drink cannot consist of other drinks that themselves consist of other drinks - for which you'd need a recursive query which MySQL doesn't feature).

Here is the query for meal 3:

```
select mc.category_name, count(*) as total_meals
from
(
  select category_id from meals where meal_id = 3
  union all
  select category_id from meals where meal_id in
    (select mapped_meal_id from meals_to_meals where meal_id = 3)
) c
join meal_categories mc using (category_id)
group by mc.category_name
order by mc.category_name;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64313b/12

Comment: Yes, you understood it right, meal can only be "one level deep". Your query looks really easy to understand, thank you very much!